# What $\mu$ represents in Gryzinski's free fall atomic model equation?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, atomic-physics, notation, atoms, magnetic-moment

When you look into the Gryzinski's atomic free fall model equation ([see wiki link here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micha%C5%82_Gryzi%C5%84ski) ), it has a variable $\mu$. What it is?

$L = \frac{1}{2} m v^2 + \frac{Ze^2}{r}+\frac{Ze}{c}[v\cdot\frac{\vec{\mu}\times\vec{r}}{r^3}]$

I am attempting to derive force equation and I am stuck on the last term because $\mu$ is not well defined, see below,

$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{dL}{dv}=\frac{dL}{dr}$

$\frac{d}{dt}(mv+\frac{Ze}{c}\frac{\vec{\mu}\times\vec{r}}{r^3})= - \frac{Ze^2}{r^2}+[v\cdot\frac{d}{dr}(\frac{\vec{\mu}\times\vec{r}}{r^3})]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It almost certainly represents the magnetic dipole moment of the electron — this is standard notation and (as noted in the wiki article) the last term is meant to account for interactions between the nucleus and the electron's magnetic moment.  According to the Wikipedia article, it is taken to be a fixed vector (the "rigid top approximation");  this does not take the interactions between the magnetic moments of the electron and the nucleus, but these interactions are small and the model chooses to neglect them.